# what is the use of the line def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) in sopaui

Tags: groovy, soapui

As I am new to the soapui so wanted to know the meaning of that line.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
```

I wanted to know what is the use of each keyword in the above line
`com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils`

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
```

What is context here in the bracket?

UPDATE from the OP's comment:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern 
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException 
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) 
def responseXML = context.expand('${getRate - Request 1#Response}') 
XmlHolder holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(responseXML)
```

Comment: anishgujral, would you please provide some more context? what do you want to achieve? or provide the script that you are working on?

Comment: import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def responseXML = context.expand('${getRate - Request 1#Response}') 
XmlHolder holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(responseXML)

Comment: As i was automating some of the request so basically i want to validate some of the parameters from response in sopa ui to check whether my goal is achieved or not .So writting groovy script to pick some parameter from reponse to match with desired result in sopaui Pro.

Answer (score 8):

`GroovyUtils` is a class provided in the SoapUI's API. And what you have mentioned is the fully qualified class.

And this `GroovyUtils` class has constructor which needs an argument `PropertyExpansionContext`.

I have to tell you one thing is that, when SoapUI is started, every script edit has some variables are already initialized.

In you case, i.e., Groovy Script test step, if you look at the top of the script editor, you would notice `context, log, testRunner` variable as shown below:

[image]

Hence, it is

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
```

Now, `groovyUtils` is object of `GroovyUtils`, so that you will be able to call the methods available in that Class.
This class has [utility methods](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/GroovyUtils.html) :

[image]

Below statement will get you `XmlHolder` object and it has lot of methods, see [here](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/XmlHolder.html) for more details

```
groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(responseXML)
```

You may find interesting examples [here](https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=xpath) to get the xpath in SoapUI's groovy script or script assertion.

Comment: @anishgujral, appreciate if you can mark it as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

GroovyUtils is a class in groovy. So, To access the utility methods of 
GroovyUtils class we need to create object of GroovyUtils class.

```
def groovyUtils = com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context object)
```

context object - It holds access to current execution session.

This is basically written to use other methods of GroovyUtils class, such
as `getXmlHolder`, `getPrettyXml` etc.

Here we go,

```
//GroovyUtils class created
def groovyUtils = com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context object)
//Call methods
def request = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(responseContent)
```

Hope, it helps you to understand.